# pip install fails in Docker container: No route to host

Tags: python, docker, pip

I've got an existing project which has dockerized everything using docker-compose. It seems to run in production, but I can't get it running on my machine.

In the `Dockerfile` I have these lines:

```
COPY requirements.txt /
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt
```

I installed the `requirements.txt` into a local virtualenv without problems (`pip install -r requirements.txt`), but when I run `docker-compose up`, it ends in this error:

```
Step 15/21 : RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt
 ---> Running in 50357eef88a5
Collecting django-braces==1.13.0 (from -r /requirements.txt (line 2))
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7efe808852e8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 113] No route to host'))': /simple/django-braces/
  [THE LINE ABOVE REPEATS 3 MORE TIMES..]
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django-braces==1.13.0 (from -r /requirements.txt (line 2)) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for django-braces==1.13.0 (from -r /requirements.txt (line 2))
ERROR: Service 'api' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c pip install -r /requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

The end of the repeating line kinda puzzles me:

```
No route to host'))': /simple/django-braces/
```

I understand it fails if it tries the "urls" `))` or `/simple/django-braces/`

The `requirements.txt` also looks fine to me. Here are the first couple lines:

```
# Django packages
django-braces==1.13.0
django-cors-headers==2.4.0
django-extensions==2.1.3
django-filter==2.0.0
```

Does anybody know what's going on here?

Comment: What is your base Docker image (the `FROM` instruction)?

Comment: Hi kramer65 - given the answer, I think this can be closed as "typo". Could you do the honours?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found it.

There was an old proxy definition in the `Dockerfile` which had to be removed.